# Redirect Issue: Wordpress database

Tags: database, redirect

I have an issue with my wordpress site that seems to relate to the settings in wordpress. However, it seems to go into a redirect loop. I can confirm upon a fresh installation the issue disappears.

I can't actually get into the wp-admin to change any of the settings. All this arose from clicking the update button to update to 4.0 then the wordpress installation went into the redirect loop for every page. Does anybody know what setting needs to be changed in the database to resolve this issue? Or is there a way to debug this issue?

Comment: Where is it redirecting to, and where is it redirecting from?

Comment: If you have any plugins installed first try disabling them via the database, if you have access. There is a guide on how to do this here [here](http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/) Though this has not been updated since 4.0.

Comment: @ChrisMorris I've checked the plugins and removed them all. The new installation I did worked with no issues. However, when I change the wp-config.php database settings and set this to the old database I get the same loop error I got.

Comment: I have just tried the link that you sent over and I removed this out of the database with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @TomJNowell acording to the google chrome plugin Redirect Path. Our URL http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/ is redirecting to https://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/ and then it continues to try and redirect over to https constantly (without going back to http). However, I've ruled htaccess and plugins out due to the new installation working. But when changing just the database it starts the same issue again.

Comment: Ah you have both http and https running on your site?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes we do. We have had for the site before the update when it worked. Then it just stopped working.